# image not showing the right image..?

Tags: php, html

Basically, user uploads an image. The image is taken, checked for the right file type and uploaded to the server here:

```
$directory = 'uploads/';
$files = glob($directory . 'audit'.$id.'_image*.jpg');
$count = 0;
if ($files !== false) {
    $count = count($files) + 1;
}

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3

    $rename =  explode('.', $_FILES['file']['name']);

    $nameString = 'audit'.$id.'_image'.$count.'.'.strtolower($rename[1]);

    //only allow certain image files
    $allowed = array(   'jpg'                   
                        );

    if (in_array(strtolower($rename[1]), $allowed)) {

        $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  //4

        $targetFile =  $targetPath. $nameString;  //5

        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6
    }

}
```

The name of the file is changed to suit the format for retrieval. That would be
`audit(iD)_image*.jpg`

or an example `audit65_image1.jpg`

Now, this works fine, and the image is uploaded.

HOWEVER, when it comes to retrieval for viewing the file.. This happens !

```
        $directory = 'uploads/';
        $files = glob($directory . 'audit'.$row['id'].'_image*.jpg');

        if (count($files) > 0) {
        ?>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <section class="panel">
                    <div class="panel-body">                            
                        <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align:center;">                              
                            <div class="panel-heading no-b">
                                <h5>Image <b>Uploads</b></h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <?php

                        foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
                            ?>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <a href=<?php echo '"'.$value.'"'; ?>><img style="box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);" src=<?php echo '"'.$value.'"'; ?> class="superbox-img"/></a>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>

                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
```

Which again, I can't see a problem with! However, on the webpage.. It will load the incorrect image, so if I uploaded 3 files, it's asif they're saved to my system or part of a system somewhere and it's causing a big issue. But it's basically showing an image that doesn't exist. If I change the file name from say `audit65_image1.jpg` to `audit65_image3.jpg` then the image shown on the webpage changes. I'm so utterly confused. I tried loading the webpage on a different computer to account for caching and it loaded the wrong image on there too even though the file does not exist for the image it's loading!

Does anyone have any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES));` so that you can check and can see what files you received?.

Comment: @RyanVincent I receive the correct files, however, in the uploads folder the file could be called `image3` yet the browser retrieves a different image. Only if it's had an image of that name previously.

Answer (score 0):

to give unique name to the image files try to add the timestamp to the name of the image before saving.